# What's the verb for singing sounds instead of words?

Tags: word-request

I think humming is when we produce a sound to sing with our mouths closed, but sometimes we do it with our mouths open like in:

> "Love is in the air ahh ah ahhh aha."

Humming would be like:

> "Love is in the air hmmm hmmm mmm mm."

Is there a verb for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two words for singing without words are *vocalise* and *scat*.

The are explained at length (with links to examples) here:

[Quora.com sing-without-words](https://www.quora.com/What-is-it-called-when-you-sing-without-words?share=1)

The dictionaries I looked at show a verb sense for *scat*, but only the noun sense for *vocalise*.

(Note that this sense of *vocalise* is pronounced differently than *vocalise* as the British spelling of *vocalize* - see
[American Heritage Dictionary *vocalise*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=vocalise))